# My computer won't update because of errors

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, ppa, update-manager

My computer won't update and instead give me these errors.
Please help if you can.
My  OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 Focal Fossa

```
Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease 
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2763B0EE7709FE97
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2763B0EE7709FE97
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2763B0EE7709FE97
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And when I try update from software updater.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove and re-add the mentioned PPA by using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
```

and then install needed updates by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try it

Comment: Is the first command supposed to take a while?

Comment: Yes, any other command which use network.

Comment: Do I have to add the kdenlive ppa if I don't want it?

Comment: Do I restart the computer?

Comment: Probably you are using modern Kdenlive package from this PPA.